# Loading items like calendar and contacts from public folder

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I've searched around looking for a way to load a calendar/contacts item from the public folder. Through Outlook it's simple, you go to the public folders and just drag-n-drop it in. I've gotten to the point accessing the calendar, but I'm not sure how to load it into Outlook through C#.

```
private void AddCalendar()
{
    Outlook._NameSpace session = null;
    Outlook.MAPIFolder publicFolders = null;
    OUtlook.MAPIFolder allPublicFolders = null;
    Outlook.MAPIFolder seCalendar = null;

    try
    {
        session = _thisApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        publicFolders = session.Folders["Public Folders"];
        allPublicFolders = publicFolders.Folders["All Public Folders"];
        seCalendar = allPublicFolders.Folders["SE Calendar"];
        // ????
        // profit
    }
    finally
    {
        //Release Items
    }
}
```

Below is a picture of what I'm trying to do. You normally just start with your own calendar, I'm trying to load a company calendar that is in the public folders.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the items in the MAPIFolder.Items collection. In your particular case, the items will be AppointmentItem, ContactItem, and DistListItem.

```
Outlook.Items items = seCalendar.Items;
for (int i = 1; i <= items.Count; i++)
{
  object item = items[i];
  Outlook.AppointmentItem appt = item as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
  if (apt != null)
  {
     MessageBox.Show(appt.Subject);
     Marshal.ReleaseComObject(appt);
  }
  Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item);
}
```

Comment: I just edited my question. How would I load AppointmentItems into my calendar view so that it displays like the image?